# CSS align based on font-family

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size, font-family

I've set the `font-family` of a *div* to `"Vermin Vibes", fantasy, serif;`, so that if the first font is not avaiable, the browser will automatically use the next one

```
#myheader {
    position: sticky;
    top: 1rem;

    text-align: center;

    font-family: "Vermin Vibes", fantasy, serif;
    font-size: 6rem;
}
```

The problem is that when the font changes *family*, it changes his size and his alignment from the top of the screen...

How can I set `top` and `font-size` to change when `font-family` changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS is only concerned with how your content is styled. You might have fonts dependent on the content, so a solution would be modifying your HTML since HTML is for defining the actual content of the page. I think this would be more related to investigated browser compatibility for your client.

By the time a fallback font-family is determined, the content has already loaded. So you'll need Javascript for that.

So determine *where* the processing for CSS styles will happen before it is compiled and evaluated by your browser. You may have to extract the font-family using Javascript and set styles conditionally if you are using plain CSS without a preprocessor.